# Spectrum Timeseries Chart

Tags: javascript, data-visualization, amcharts

[image: Range bar graph with timeseries data]

I'm having trouble finding a chart type similar to the one I diagrammed above. It resembles a chromosome, spectrum, or barcode. It has a column (light-blue) which represents the range of values in a dataset in relation to a threshold. I want a user to be able to indicate a time range and see which values (dark-blue) were observed within that time range.

Eventually I want to show multiple datasets like this next to each other, where they share a normalized threshold. This way I can quickly see all my datasets in relation to their individual thresholds for the same time range.

[image: multiple datasets on normalized threshold]

A stacked bar chart appears closest visually, but it's not meant for timeseries data, and its also not meant for binary groups (within range, not in range).

I need to create this for the web. I'm using amcharts for other charts in the project so I'd like to use that if possible but I'm open to any other libraries. Suggestions of similar chart types, charting libraries, or amcharts workarounds would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I could recommend trying rotated (chart.rotate = true) amCharts serial chart, which will allow having date-time data on vertical axis. Instead of stacked column chart I would use guides (you can set date and toDate for a guide and specify fill color/opacity too).

The only problem I see is that guides span through full width of a chart. To solve this I would place two (or whatever number you need) charts next to each other.

Answer (score 0):

After quite a bit more searching I found I could get a pretty close result using Highchart's 'column range' chart. I still have to manually loop through time series data or re-pull it to get the values for every query, but that's not such a big deal.

I use categories for the data sources and series for range and observed bands. Values that match the query go into the observed series with the appropriate category index.

```
series: [{
        name: 'range',
        stack: 0,
        data: [{
            x: 0,
            color: 'blue',
            low: -9,
            high: 3
        }, {
            x: 1,
            color: 'green',
            low: -2,
            high: 2
        }]
    },{
        name: 'observed',
        stack: 0,
        data: [{
            x: 0,
            low: 1,
            high: 1.1
        }, {
            x: 0,
            low: -5,
            high: -4.5
        }, {
            x: 0,
            low: -4,
            high: -2
        }, {
            x: 1,
            low: -1,
            high: 0
        }]
    }]
```

Here's a link to the complete JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tschie/6wfkpkt9/4/